# What type of curve is used for pricing fx forwards?

Tags: fx

When pricing FX forwards, what type of curves are used? OIS, LIBOR, SOFR, etc?

Comment: Usually, at least for the most liquid currencies, this works from an FX swap curve directly, i.e. starting from a "base" curve (usually a risk free rate in your accounting currency) you bootstrap the curve from quoted pips for the respective currency pair by bridging via the USD

Comment: In tier 1 Banks, usually STIRT desks price FX Forwards based on combinations of strategies. Many curves are constructed for each Ccy pair using points from Reuters broker pages and as well as interest differentials from interest rate curves